# Web Process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 second of launch

Tags: python, heroku

the title is the error I'm receiving upon deploying a simple python desktop game to heroku.

```
2021-05-05T05:41:30.035966+00:00 app[web.1]: Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
2021-05-05T05:42:27.550299+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-05-05T05:42:27.600881+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-05-05T05:42:27.695468+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-05-05T05:42:27.805296+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-05T05:55:08.163630+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ancient-springs-11881.herokuapp.com request_id=b8e64b86-04f0-4aad-be3e-e3b031bced98 fwd="100.33.254.217" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-05T05:55:08.519153+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ancient-springs-11881.herokuapp.com request_id=760a55d0-8f9d-4b5a-ae7d-72a8f1cee310 fwd="100.33.254.217" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Procfile `web: python3 main.py`

If I understand correctly, I need to bind to some port to host the app online but I'm unable to find one? Anyone come upon this issue in the past?

Comment: What do you mean by "you deployed a python dekstop game" to Heroku? Heroku runs headless. There is no desktop. -------- There can be two solutions: Either your app doesn't use a port at which point you just change the process type in your `Procfile` from `web` to `worker` or anything else. And if you have a port you need to listen to it `import os; PORT = os.environ["PORT"]`

Comment: Let me reword this: It's a single python script that is a game. I am trying to host the script on Heroku so anyone can access it and play it using the link. I am aware that it is a not a 'desktop' game if it's being run online. Unfortunately, whenever I change the process type in the Procfile to worker, I receive an H14 error "No Web processes running"

Comment: So do you have a `PORT` for your game or not? When you host it locally does a game window automatically pop up or do you open the browser and connect to an URL. If so what is the URL. Is there a port number at the end of your URL? Where does that port number come from?

Comment: I just launch it from the text editor. It's not hosted locally so there is no Port

Comment: If it has no port than people won't be able to access your game via the web browser. Your application is probably not compatible for Heroku.